# Cannot update Xamarin from VS 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing Xamarin application on VS 2015 Enterprise. I have a Xamarin update, but when I click to install button from Xamarin Updates dialog, it disappears. I don't see any errors. I use VS 2015 update 3, .NET Version 4.7.02046, Xamarin 4.4 (want to update to 4.6). Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you try just re-installing Xamarin Studio?

Comment: I don't use Xamarin Studio. I use Xamarin inside VS 2015 on Windows.

Comment: Apologises, I overlooked that. But the same question still applies. Did try re-installing VS? Doing so should automatically install the latest version of the Xamarin class libraries

Comment: It was my last option, I thought there is some other solution, but at the end I had to re-install VS, and now I have the last Xamarin version. Thanks :)

Comment: Good to know, @Dragana. I have created an answer so that others dont open this question when a solution has already been provided. An acceptance of the answer would also help me and everyone else alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reinstalling Visual Studio entirely?

It could be that your installation is corrupt, which means that the updater will have difficulties properly applying the new updates for the Xamarin class libraries.

Comment: Yes, I did. I completely reinstalled my VS and Xamarin latest version came with it.